# Teamcity with Subversion post commit script on windows

Tags: shell, batch-file, svn, teamcity

We would like Teamcity to build our solutions on every commit into subversion. 
Following the documentation, we are to create a .sh script :-

```
SERVER=https://buildserver-url
USER=buildserver-user
PASS="<password>"

LOCATOR=$1

# The following is one-line:
(sleep 10;  curl --user $USER:$PASS -X POST "$SERVER/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/commitHookNotification?locator=$LOCATOR" -o /dev/null) >/dev/null 2>&1 <&1 &

exit 0
```

Subversion is running on a windows environment, and so the .sh file will fail.
We are trying to convert this into a .bat file of which we have :-

```
set SERVER=https://buildserver-url
set USER=buildserver
set PASS=password

LOCATOR=%1%

(timeout 10;  curl --user %USER%:%PASS% -X POST "%SERVER%/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/commitHookNotification?locator=%LOCATOR%" -o /dev/null) >/dev/null 2>%1% <%1% &

exit 0
```

However, this is still failing  when trying to execute with

```
"The system cannot find the path specified"
```

It seems that perhaps we havnt converted this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Are the programs you're referencing (such as `curl` and `timeout.exe`) in locations that are present in the `$PATH`/`%PATH%` variable? How about any other files you're referencing - are you specifying full paths

Side note: Did you install `curl` and `timeout.exe` on the Windows server?

Also, `/dev/null` does not exist on Windows; you need to redirect to `NUL`. You can't just change the file extension and some of your syntax and expect a bash script to work on Windows.

Were I in your shoes, I'd skip batch altogether and write the script in something modern and sane like Powershell.